# Remove bottom line (blue) in app from default generated Android theme

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I want to get remove the blue line at the bottom of the window from my layout. I suppose that this is generated with the theme.
Below is a screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: show your xml, this is nothing that is part of a standard theme'

Comment: yeah... there was no such question from me. Sorry!

Comment: I had this in my activity_main.xml

`<android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#33b5e5"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="#fff" />`

Comment: you have background set to that color `android:background="#33b5e5"`